# Store <options> in variable and put them in any <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a `<select>` tag and plenty of options
instead of `copy`-> `paste` these options can I store them in a variable and reuse them?

## Example:

```
<script>
   var options  = '<option value=0>test0</option>\n'+
                  '<option value=1>test1</option>\n'+
                  '<option value=2>test2</option>'

   <select>
      options
   </select>
</script>
```

Comment: uhm ... yes you can do that?

Comment: That's possible but you have to use valid JavaScript. Like `document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = options;`

Comment: Do you mean reuse the markup, or reuse the `Option` elements?

Comment: Reuse the options element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to add options on page load to specific select element using append (jQuery) or innerHTML(pure js)

check the following code and jsbin example I have added for your specific requirement.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var options  = '<option value=0>test0</option>\n'+
                  '<option value=1>test1</option>\n'+
                  '<option value=2>test2</option>'

  jQuery('#select_element').append(options)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<select id="select_element">
 </select>
```

```
//with pure js
document.getElementById('select_element').innerHTML = options;
```

JSBIN demo - https://jsbin.com/yibezof/edit?html,js,console,output